# Searching through multiple SharePoint lists and then concatenating them into one

Tags: jquery, list, search, sharepoint-2010, concatenation

So this is a rather large, and potentially awkward, problem my manager has tasked me with. We have around 1800 lists; each list contains a dozen columns, with three columns being, "building", "location", and "manager." My manager is requesting the ability to do a search based off of building, location, and manager, and have all lists with these matching values be concatenated into a single list.

I'm not sure where to even begin searching for a solution to this problem. I'm familiar with jquery, so if that helps. If anyone has a suggestion on how to achieve this, if it's even possible, you'll have my thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the name of the list must match something, or the list must contain something when you say "it matches". Where are the locations, buildings and managers stored and how many of each are there? What platform are you on?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. 

Each of our lists contains dozen or so columns, with 3 being "building", "location", and "manager". Every lists has these columns. What my manager wants is for a query to be run based on those three specific columns and pull up ALL lists which has matching data in the columns to what was queried. 

We're running SharePoint 2010.